# Alert prompt should appear if the time spent is more than the estimate

Tags: rational-team-concert

Here's My scenario, User working on a Task and keeping estimated time and working more than the estimated time. To avoid that, the user should get alert prompt should appear if the time spent is more than the estimate time.